# Windows SharePoint Desktop Sync

Tags: windows, sharepoint, synchronization, microsoft-office-365

I can remove the files and it will sync properly then upload them again but if I go to do another initial sync I'll have this same issue. Is this just an issue with how the files are being named? They some how are accessible and usable just fine but doing an initial sync I get this error.

I've tried doing repairs from some of the desktops and still have this issue.

The files are managed from 30 devices, all ranging from apple, windows, and android from in the office to out in the field on 3G.

Could incomplete uploads for example play a part of this issue and problem? After checking one of the files online the online previewer seems to fail but the other files are ok and the one that did not work with the previewer is one of the files in question.

Is there a way to fix these broken files if they are infact the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple things than cause a sync failure.  It doesn't look like the usual culprits apply to you

- Folder + File name < 250 characters
- No illegal characters or names

Since these are syncing from multiple locations are there any locked files when you run this sync?  Do you have Check-in / out enabled on the library?  Try turning that off.

Make sure version control is turned on the library.

You mention it fails on initial sync.  When you "seed" the library with the file, are you letting the new file populate the other systems or are you trying to sync existing files?  I would remove the file from the sync library and make sure it's removed from all the other devices (just to test this theory).  Seed it from one device and allow the other devices to "download" the file.